# Sequelize instance methods not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use Sequelize's instance method to validate a password on login attempt.
I have defined the User model as :

```
var User = sequelize.define('User',{
    id:{
          type:DataTypes.BIGINT,
          autoIncrement: true,
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey:true
        },
    username:{
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          unique:true
        },
    password:{
          type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
    ...
  },
  {
    classMethods:{
        associate:function(models){
        ...
        }
      }
  },
  {
    instanceMethods:{
        validatePassword:function(password){
          return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        }
      }
  }
);
  return User;
}
```

In my login route I do the following :

- 1) Retrieve username & password from request body
- 2) Check if username exists in database
- 3) If user exists, get user object and compare sent password with hashed password in database using validatePassword method.

Here is the relevant code

```
var username = req.body.username || "";
var password = req.body.password || "";
models.User.findOne({ where: {username: username} }).
then(
    function(user) {
     if(user){
      console.log(user.validatePassword(password));
     }
 ....
```

Each time I try to login I get the following error

```
[TypeError: user.validatePassword is not a function]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `user` is not null?

Comment: @Hopeful Llama nope i can ***console.log(user)*** and retrieve all info

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are using the sequelize model definition api incorrectly.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#expansion-of-models

This is the correct way:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User',{}, {
  classMethods: {
    method1: ...
  },
  instanceMethods: {
    method2: ...
  }
});
```

not like this:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User',{}, {
  classMethods: {
    method1: ...
  }
},{
  instanceMethods: {
    method2: ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Yep that fixed it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who's having a similar problem, I ran into the same issue but using Sequelize 5.21.5.  According to this article, [Sequelize Instance Methods](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/instance-methods), starting with Sequelize 4.0 and above, you have to use the prototype methodology in order to define instance methods like so:

```
    // Adding an instance level methods.
    User.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
      return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};
```

Comment: I can't access to this when I use the function on an instance. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: @KevinMamaqi don't use an arrow function. it might affect to `this` keyword

Answer (score 10):

We can add instanceLevelMethods to prototype,

```
User.prototype.your-instance-level-method-name = function() {
    return 'foo';
};
```

I did it like this:

```
// Adding an instance level methods.
User.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I was hoping to make the instance and class methods work on my Model, but the other suggestions do not work, and I get a "is not a function" error code.

Answer (score 2):

I use this approach:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const constants = require('../constants/users');

module.exports = (Sequelize, type) => {
  const User = Sequelize.define(constants.TABLE_NAME, {
    username: {
      type: type.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: type.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    // bla bla
  });

  const setSaltAndPassword = async function(user) {
    if (user.changed('password')) {
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(constants.PASSWORD_SALT_SIZE);
      user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
    }
  };

  User.prototype.validPassword = async function(password) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
  };

  User.beforeCreate(setSaltAndPassword);
  User.beforeUpdate(setSaltAndPassword);

  return User;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

as at sequelize "sequelize": "^5.21.7" accessing the instanceMethods as shown by @user1695032 returns undefined.

here's what i found after several hours of getting undefined in the console.log() passing in the user object return from the query below:

```
User {
  dataValues: {
    id: 1,
    firtName: null,
    lasteName: null,
    email: 'ugbanawaji.ekenekiso@ust.edu.ng',
    phone: null,
    password: '$2b$10$yEWnBFMAe15RLLgyU3XlrOUyw19c4PCmh8GJe9QVz3YkbdzK5fHWu',
    createdAt: 2020-05-27T21:45:02.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-27T21:45:02.000Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 1,
    firtName: null,
    lasteName: null,
    email: 'ugbanawaji.ekenekiso@ust.edu.ng',
    phone: null,
    password: '$2b$10$yEWnBFMAe15RLLgyU3XlrOUyw19c4PCmh8GJe9QVz3YkbdzK5fHWu',
    createdAt: 2020-05-27T21:45:02.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-27T21:45:02.000Z
  },
  _changed: {},
  **_modelOptions: {**
    timestamps: true,
    validate: {},
    freezeTableName: false,
    underscored: false,
    paranoid: false,
    rejectOnEmpty: false,
    whereCollection: { email: 'ugbanawaji.ekenekiso@ust.edu.ng' },
    schema: null,
    schemaDelimiter: '',
    defaultScope: {},
    scopes: {},
    indexes: [],
    name: { plural: 'Users', singular: 'User' },
    omitNull: false,
    **instanceMethods: { comparePasswords: [Function: comparePasswords] },**
    hooks: { beforeValidate: [Array] },
    sequelize: Sequelize {
      options: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      dialect: [MysqlDialect],
      queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
      models: [Object],
      modelManager: [ModelManager],
      connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
      importCache: [Object]
    }
  },
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
      'id',        'firtName',
      'lasteName', 'email',
      'phone',     'password',
      'createdAt', 'updatedAt'
    ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

the code before the error:

```
 models.User.findOne({where: {email: req.body.email}}).then((user)=>{
            console.log(user)
            if(!user) {
                res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authentication failed!' });
                } else {
                user.comparePasswords(req.body.password, (error, isMatch) =>{
                    console.log(error + ' -- ' + isMatch)
                    if(isMatch && !error) {
                        const token = jwt.sign(
                            { username: user.username },
                            keys.secret,
                            { expiresIn: '30h' }
                        );

                        res.status(200).json({ success: true,message: 'signed in successfully', token: 'JWT ' + token });
                    } else {
                        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Login failed!' });
                    }
                });
            }
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'There was an error!'});
        })
```

this cause **TypeError: user.comparePasswords is not a function**

after changing this line:

```
** user.comparePasswords(req.body.password, (error, isMatch) =>{} **
```

to this:

```
** user._modelOptions.instanceMethods.comparePasswords(req.body.password, (error, isMatch) =>{}**
```

booooom! everything worked